# Excel automation failing on server Access Denied / HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)

Tags: .net, office-interop

I've got a Windows service working in dev and pre-prod that uses Office interop.  I'm attempting to deploy in production (also Server 2008R2) and it's not working when it attempts to start Excel in the first place (create an Application instance).  Error:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following
>   error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005
>   (E_ACCESSDENIED)).

- The C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop folder exists. (and sys32's for needless good measure)
- Excel is installed and activated.
- The account under which the service runs is a local admin.
- Verified account has DCOM privileges.
- I recommended against this direction in the first place.
- Open XML is not an option at the moment.
- I understand MS doesn't recommend this.

Has anyone encountered any other solutions to this error when instantiating Excel in code?

Comment: It seems that you have covered pretty much all bases, if you login into this local admin account, are you able to open Excel?

Comment: Could you solve this problem? How?

Comment: I'm sorry.  It was resolved but I do not recall how.  It was an issue on how Excel was installed / set up vs. a code change on my side.